# How should 'a posteriori' and 'a priori' be used?

Tags: academic-writing

I'm currently writing a scientific report, and have noted that a future investigator could use certain tactics to make their life easier. However, I only discovered this **after** having gone through the experiment. I've tried writing this result like as:

> This knowledge is *a posteriori*, however, and other arrangements could have their...

Is this the correct way to use the phrase? Reading examples online doesn't seem to use it like this, though it seems sound to me.

Answer (score 1):

Even in academic writing, it's a good idea to be as clear as possible, although many academic writers seem to forget that fact.  If you're using a phrase that you're not completely sure you're using correctly, or that you think might be easily misinterpreted, I would advise you to simply replace it.

In this particular case, while the phrase *a priori* is relatively common and widely understood, its linked opposite, *a posteriori* is much less so.

*Note: If your question is solely whether or not your usage is* technically correct *in this case, it would be better asked on http://english.stackexchange.com instead.*